# New-AzureRmWebAppBackup cmdlet returns "Number of allowed backups exceeded"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

We are scripting a backup procedure for unused resource groups in Azure which includes backing up the web apps we have deployed. For that, we are using the `New-AzureRmWebAppBackup` cmdlet.

At first, this was working without any issue, but suddenly we have started receiving the following error:

`New-AzureRmWebAppBackup : Number of allowed backups exceeded. 0 backups were processed in last 24 hours.`

I can't find any reference to this anywhere online, and the documentation for `New-AzureRmWebAppBackup` doesn't list this as far as I can tell.

Can someone please assist or at least explain what could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems related to the limit of the backups, there is a limit(manual+scheduled) depends on the pricing tier.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

[image]

Comment: I see. We were unaware of this limitation. It appears that we're going to have to scale the App Service Plan up to Standard at minimum to back up the App Service.